# What are the benefits of using NoSQL in mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, nosql

I have seen a lot of NoSQL libraries for mobile platform, but the main thing comes in mind, why we are trying to use NoSQL in mobile systems which are already having very limited space.

Please clarify the scenarios, where they could be beneficial over Sqlite3.

Comment: NoSQL actually exist , not widely used but helpful in mobile development era.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Application Development (Android, iOS) platforms having complex & rigid structure with relational database. For simplicity of handling of data.As developers come up with new ideas and features for their applications, making changes becomes a time-consuming task because constant changes have to be made to the database schema.

Another issue with mobile applications that NoSQL addresses is the need for constant updates. After an application has been released, maintenance becomes a major concern, among other things to consider. Because NoSQL is document based, fixing certain types of bugs and other problems doesn’t require a complete overhaul of the database, because the changes made by developers don’t necessarily affect every other aspect of the application.

Finally, NoSQL is well known for its scalability. Unlike relational databases, NoSQL databases scale outward rather than vertically.  Now a days there are consideration of NoSQL. For More you can read below articles :-

1. [Why NoSQL Trumps Relational Databases for Mobile Applications](http://www.techopedia.com/2/29256/development/mobile-development/why-nosql-trumps-relational-databases-for-mobile-applications)
2. [Why NoSQL is Better for Mobile Apps](http://www.dataversity.net/why-nosql-is-better-for-mobile-apps/)

Hope this helps you !

Comment: [Link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). You can use links as source or reference for further reading, but you should always sumarize the information they contain.

Comment: @philiipp there is no meaning of copy pasting here the others content so it is good to show such links.  I am disagree with you.

Comment: When you would like to discuss it, discuss it on the linked meta-question. It explains the reasoning behind this very well.

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL is best leveraged for unstructured and semi-structured data, thus, enter mobile application development. I would break down the benefits as such:

Low-Latency Data Storage: NoSQL databases are built to serve predictable, low-latency requests and provide a highly available experience to end users.

Scale for Peak Loads: peer to peer NoSQL databases make it easy to add additional capacity and scale out quickly versus scaling vertically with relational DB's.

[Riak](http://basho.com/riak/) (by Basho) is a good one to take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

not all nosql databases need much space, today we have some lightweight solutions, like iBoxDB.net and [iBoxDB.java](https://github.com/iboxdb/forjava).
and what are the benefits of using nosql, there has a scenario

[A database for Q&A and RPG games](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/199279-A-database-for-Q-amp-A-and-RPG-games)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that in creating and using a non-sql key/value data store (https://github.com/AaronBratcher/SimpleDB) that I work in a style that uses less memory at runtime. Instead of keeping an array of objects for my long tables, I only keep an array of keys, getting the object values as needed.

I've also found that as I prototype and change the format of my classes, something I've been doing a lot of as the dynamics of my project changes, I don't need to spend as much time refactoring my db layer class because I simply change the class init/value code and spend more time working on more important aspects of my project.